# Token contract for exchange fund manager

Tags: contract-development, web3js, exchanges

I'm seeing lot's of address like this for exchange sites that they manage their user balances in a single address like this:

CoinExchange.io: https://etherscan.io/address/0x4b01721f0244e7c5b5f63c20942850e447f5a5ee

Binance: https://etherscan.io/address/0x3f5ce5fbfe3e9af3971dd833d26ba9b5c936f0be

Are there any example contract? I'd like to see that.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the contract that's the "Normal Account" (or externally owned accounts). So it's just regular account that can be accessed using Primary Key. No magic behind it.

http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/account-management.html